# Unable to click on a button using watir-webdriver

Tags: css, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

Here is my html:

```
<p class="actions">
  <input style="float: right" id="submit" type="submit" name="Create account" value="Update profile">
  <button name="cancel" style="padding: 10px 10px" onclick="window.close(); return false">Cancel</button>
  <button name="delete" style="padding: 10px 10px" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://88888.dev2.ext-dev.mysite.com/plugins/social/profile/delete?sessionKey=521f6a65e4b01c799ac48260&amp;webSocketIdentifier=521f6a65e4b01c799ac4825f'; return false">Delete account</button>
</p>
```

I have used:

```
delete_account=@browser.element(:css => "p.actions > delete").click
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Watir, it is often better for readability to avoid css and xpath unless there is no other solution.

You should be able to do:

```
@browser.button(:name => 'delete').click
```

If the paragraph is an important part in differentiating the delete link, you may need to do:

```
@browser.p(:class => 'actions').button(:name => 'delete').click
```

If you really want to use css, I think it should have been:

```
@browser.element(:css => "p.actions > [name=delete]").click
```

or

```
@browser.element(:css => "p.actions > button[name=delete]").click
```

Note that "delete" is the value of the button's name attribute, not its class.

As per discussion in the comments, the element was also in a popup browser window. This has to be accessed using:

```
@browser.windows.last.use{ browser.button(:name => 'delete').click }
```

Comment: I have tried above too .. & I get the following error 
 unable to locate element, using {:class=>"actions", :tag_name=>"p"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

Comment: It works with just the snippet of html that you gave. That means there is something else about your page. Are these controls that get displayed after some ajax or javascript event is fired? You might want to check [this list](http://jkotests.wordpress.com/unable-to-locate-element/) for common reasons for this exception to occur.

Comment: Disagree about using XPath over CSS.  CSS is better supported cross browser than XPath and often faster

Comment: @RobbieWareham, I think you misread my answer. I did not say anything about using XPath over CSS. I said to use Watir's API over XPath and CSS. If you are using xpath or css, it defeats the purpose of using the Watir gem at all. You should have just used the selenium-webdriver gem and avoided the unnecessary layer.

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for your suggestions. 
I am not able to click on the button yet. Honestly speaking I have tried all the above options. This button is pop up which shows up when the user wants to delete the account so it is Ajax and I have used 
@browser.window.use and then trying to click on the button. Other things work just fine .. its just this button I am not able to locate using any of the options mentioned above :(

Comment: If you are using ajax, are you sure it is actually a new window that is opened? It is more likely just a div tag that gets displayed over everything. Before you click the button, I would suggest trying `@browser.p(:class => 'actions').wait_until_present`.

Comment: its a pop up window and as you said its a <div class="header-wrapper"> & has a form and p in it which holds these  buttons

Comment: It would help if you show more of your html, but I still think you should try the `wait_until_present` code.

Comment: @JustinKo I am sorry I left a bit early yesterday hence I couldn't respond; here is my html

Comment: @JustinKo <html><head><body><divclass="header-wrapper"><div class="header">Update your Profile</div></div>
<form method="post" action=""><input type="hidden"name="_utf8" value="☃"><p><p class="actions"><input style="float: right" id="submit" type="submit" name="Create account" value="Update profile"><button name="cancel" style="padding: 10px 10px" onclick="window.close(); return false">Cancel</button><button name="delete" style="padding: 10px 10pxonclick="window.location.href = 'https://1111111111.e4b04782e12a79eb'; return false">Delete account</button></p>

Comment: What happened when you tried switching windows? `@browser.windows.last.use{ browser.button(:name => 'delete').click }`

Comment: @JustinKo - What happened when you tried switching windows? @browser.windows.last.use{ browser.button(:name => 'delete').click }
This did the trick. Thanks a bunch for your help; I was using window.use which wasn't helping. Your snippet did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML does not contain the following html, then your CSS selector is wrong;

```
<p class='actions>
    <delete></delete>
</p>
```

Comment: I have also tried delete_account=@browser.element(:css => "p.actions > button:delete").click
So any other suggestions to click on the delete button here ?

Comment: What does ":" mean in CSS terms? I haven't used that before.

Comment: If the button class is delete then use "p.actions > button.delete".  If the button id is delete then use "p.actions > button#delete"

Comment: Just seen your html, so use "p.actions > button[name='delete']"